# Display user data inside div - blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display user data in div blocks depending upon the number of users. I will get the number of users and data from server using ajax. I want to display the user data in a separate div block. If the number of users is 2, I want to display two blocks , 3 users in three blocks...I defined a div

```
<div class = "users> </div>.
```

Inside this div, I want to append the users details like

```
<div class=" user1"> <p><span class="name"></span></p>
<p><span class="age"></span></p>
<p><span class="address"></span></p>
</div>
```

using jQuery. If there are two users, I have to display the blocks in the center. Depending upon the number of users , I have to align the blocks.(For ex : 6 users - 3 in one row)
How to display the data inside the div?

code:

```
 <div class="users">
               <div class="user1">

                        <p> <span class="name">  </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="age">          </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="address">     </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="phone">    </span> </p>
                    </div>


                 <div class="user2">

                        <p> <span class="name">  </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="age">          </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="address">     </span> </p>
                        <p> <span class="phone">    </span> </p>
                    </div>

            </div>
for(var user_name in res) {

  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 10000,
        dataType: 'json',
 url:  multidashboard_info_url + '?client=' + user_name,
        async: true,
     })
     .done(function(data) {
     console.log(" success and data is ",data);
        var dashboard_info = data["dashboard_info"];
        var name = dashboard_info["details"]["name"],
        age = dashboard_info["details"]["age"],
        address = dashboard_info["details"]["address"],             



     })
     .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
     })
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have any code that makes clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: after you get the data from your ajax you can always create a copy of the div using jquery clone and replace the value of it from the resulting ajax data and then append it on your html :D hope it helps

Comment: <div class="users>    <div>. How to define 'div' for each users inside this div?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method to add content inside html and for multiple solution, you need to create a dynamic function like this:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/631ew9rn/2/)

```
function addUserData($selector,name,age,address) {
    $selector.append('<p><span class="name">'+ name +'</span></p>' +
                     '<p><span class="age">'+ age +'</span></p>' +
                     '<p><span class="address">'+ address +'</span></p>');
}

var name1 = 'John',
age1 = 23,
address1 = 'New York';
addUserData($('.user1'),name1,age1,address1);

var name2 = 'Wall',
age2 = 32,
address2 = 'Istanbul';
addUserData($('.user2'),name2,age2,address2);
```

Comment: actually this works for two users. I don't know the number of users . In the my code, I have written only for two users.

Comment: @Chandar mate you can get user data length, than create a for loop and inside for loop you can add my function. I've build an example like this because you didn't share the data.

Comment: for(var user_name in res) {
  
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
      timeout: 10000,
      dataType: 'json',
  url:  multidashboard_info_url + '?client=' + user_name,
      async: true,
   })
   .done(function(data) {
   console.log(" success and data is ",data);
         var dashboard_info = data["dashboard_info"];
        var name = dashboard_info["details"]["name"],
        age = dashboard_info["details"]["age"],
        address = dashboard_info["details"]["address"],       


         
   })
   .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
   }) 
  }

Comment: I shared my code. i want to add a class for each user and then display the data. How to add class for each user and thn append data?

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try something like this:

```js
//this object you should be returned as a json_encoded(USERS_ARRAY) at your php controller
var jsonEncodedObject = '[{"name":"Gonsalo Sousa","age":23,"address":"Some Address"},{"name":"Jonh Doe","age":40,"address":"Some Address"}]';

//parseJSON to use with jscript
var users = $.parseJSON(jsonEncodedObject);

//now run the object using $.each()
$(users).each(function(index) {
  //appends each user to the #users <div>
  $('#users').append('<div class="user' + index + '"><p><span class="name">' + this.name + '</span></p>' + '<p><span class="age">' + this.age + '</span></p>' + '<p><span class="address">' + this.address + '</span></p></div>');
});
```

```css
[class*="user"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe this can help you

```
var i = 0;
jQuery(dashboard_info["details"]).each(function(){
    var className = "user"+i;
    jQuery('#users').append('<div class="'+className+'">/*rest of your html*/</div>')
    i++;
});
```

Comment: if you see in my code , var dashboard_info = data["dashboard_info"];  The details is present inside var name  = dashboard_info["details"]["name"] similarly age = dashboard_info["details"]["age"]. how to loop the details?

Comment: First of all you wanna loop the `dashboard_info["details"]` to get it's contents like `name, age, address` **or** you wanna loop a set of `dashboard_info["details"][n]`?

Comment: **Note** `dashboard_info ` must be an `Object` for this `dashboard_info["details"]["other_index"]` to work,for some reason jscript accepts only numeric indexes for arrays.
For the looping you can use jQuery using `jQuery(dashboard_info["details"]).each(function(){});` and also with jscript `for(var i in dashboard_info["details"]){}` `i` will be the index `dashboard_info["details"][i]`

Comment: thanks. if i use jQuery(dashboard_info["details"]).each(function(index){});. Index is same for all the users - class="user0" remains same for all.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use `class="user1"` `class="user2"`? I'm asking this because you can do something like `jQuery('.user').eq(numeric_index)`this will return the `user` at `numeric_index` position on DOM.

You can also declare a variable outside the `jQuery.each()` to count iterations `var i = 0;` then inside the loop you simply do `i++;` **`i`** will become the user index `class="user'+i+'"`

Comment: no i am not using user1 and user2. There can be any number of users. I just want to add index to each user in <div class='user1'>... class='user10'>